# Ionic2 Native : Hide location bar in android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

Plugin

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

app.module.ts

```
const browser = this.iab.create('http://example.com','_blank','location = no,toolbar= no');
```

edited the Android.manifest.xml

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Edited the InAppBrowser.java

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

After all this I am still getting this Location bar.[image]

Please guys help me out with this. Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `options` string **must not** contain any **blank** space.So you have to write it as shown below without spaces.

```
'location=no,toolbar=no'
```